# ubuntu11.04 blackscreen when external monitor connected

Tags: ubuntu, external-display

my thinkpad x201i has ubuntu 11.04 installed. i try to connect an external monitor(a HP LCD) to the laptop. it worked at first time, everything is fine. but when i connect the monitor the second time, laptop screen goes complete black and HP monitor flickers like crazy. any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: my xorg.conf 

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "Monitor0"
VendorName "Unknown"
ModelName "Unknown"
HorizSync 28.0 - 75.0
VertRefresh 43.0 - 75.0
Option "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "Device0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Default Screen"
Device "Device0"
Monitor "Monitor0"
SubSection "Display"
Modes "1280x800@60" "800x600@60"
EndSubSection
EndSection